# Show $ \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k} x^{\sqrt{2}+k }$ converges uniformly on $[0,b]$ for $b$ less than 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Show $\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k} x^{\sqrt{2}+k } }$ converges uniformly on $[0,b]$ for $b$ less than $1$.

The series converges by alternating series test, since the term $x^{\sqrt{2}+k}$ goes to zero in the interval,along with being monotonically decreasing (except at zero).

But l don't think it shows uniform convergence. Which test should l use to prove uniform convergence ? The Weierstrass M test and Abel's test don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a hundred percent sure, but the fastest way is to use total convergence.
In fact total convergence $\implies$ uniform convergence.
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|(-1)^{k} x^{\sqrt{2}+k}\right|=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left| x^{\sqrt{2}}x^k\right|=x^{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left| x^k\right|
\end{equation}
Now, we now by our hypothesis that $x \in [0,b]$ so we can say $x^k \leq b^k \ \forall x \in [0,b]$ and $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$.
Therefore
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left| x^k\right| \leq  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left| b^k\right|=\sum_{k=1}^\infty  b^k
\end{equation}
Since $\displaystyle{|b| <1, \ \sum_{k=1}^\infty  b^k}$ converges because it is a geometric series. It follow that the original series converges uniformly in the given interval

Comment: Absolute convergence doesn't prove uniform convergence ( from what l understand and know )

Comment: Absolute convergence doesn't prove uniform convergence, but total convergence yes